# Permission denied cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have downloaded a file, and saved in a directory

```
cordova.file.externalRootDirectory+'appName/'+file;
```

and I am using cordova-plugin-file-opener2 plugin to access that file.
But I am getting following error in few phones:

```
ava.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/appName/7cc45cf629027499_05750_BG.jpg (Permission denied)
```

I have checked that file exists at this location.

Answer (score 0):

This depend on the OS, on the new OS version like Nouget you must have read and write permission . Since Android 6.0, the Android permissions checking mechanism has been changed. To make it easier, just use https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permission plugin.

Comment: I have checked in two phones both with same Android version i.e. lollipop and in one it is working and in other its not.

Comment: Oh. Well, the log say ava.io.FileNotFoundException. That's mean file is not exist if i'm not mistaken

Comment: Are you using any plugin to check whether file exist

Answer (score 0):

on android I just used the following directory and it worked like a charm:

```
cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory
```

[information source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148545/cannot-open-files-with-fileopener2-but-not-getting-an-error-in-android)

By the way, the *FileNotFoundException* also occurs when you have permission issues (at least in this plugin).